# How to get simultaneous work of several apps?

Tags: android

I want to run 3 apps at the same time and launch them from another app.

One way:

```
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("x.x.x0"));
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("x.x.x1"));
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("x.x.x2"));
```

Apps work one after another.

Another way:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("x.x.x0"));
    }
}.start();

new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("x.x.x1"));
    }
}.start();

new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("x.x.x2"));
    }
}.start();
```

Only the last app works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to launch several activities at once, so there is rarely used option of [startActivities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities(android.content.Intent[],%20android.os.Bundle)) instead of calling multiple `startActivity`.

The documentation of this method also describes why your option of calling startActivity 3 times doesn't work:

> This is generally the same as calling startActivity(android.content.Intent) for the first Intent in the array, that activity during its creation calling startActivity(android.content.Intent) for the second entry, etc.

Android expects to launch only one activity by startActivity. The second one should be only launched from onCreate of the first one. If you expect all 3 activity to be launched simultaneously, then probably this note is also important for your:

> Note that unlike that approach, generally none of the activities except the last in the array will be created at this point, but rather will be created when the user first visits them (due to pressing back from the activity on top).

Comment: And what to do?

Comment: @Nxtpr you just provide an array of intents into this method. Very convenient

Comment: Intent[] intnts = {getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage
        ("x.x.x0"),
        getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage
                ("x.x.x1"),
        getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage
                ("x.x.x2")};
startActivities(intnts);   Only the last app works.

Comment: @Nxtpr if you mean that only last app's activity got created right away then yes, it's what they stay in their documentation in the last note that I left in my response. It basically creates a virtual back stack. If you want all the activities to be created, then you have to launch them one by one in onCreate of newly created activity. This approach would work of course if you have access to these applications.

Comment: @Nxtpr However, you could try to experiment with NEW_TASK and MULTIPLE_TASK flags for intents if you implement some kind of application launcher:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK. It could probably solve your problems if you are ok with trying to launch all these applications in different tasks.

Comment: Chain start with **onCreate** works. Trying for stable result now.

Comment: @Nxtpr what do you mean by stable result?

Comment: It works with net service. One net instanse per pakage. Stable result means error correction and so on.